# How can I use iptables as a per-user whitelist web filter on Linux?

Tags: linux, iptables, whitelist, webfilter

I'm trying to use `iptables` to create a web filter on a local machine that whitelists a list of websites and blacklists everything else on a per-user basis. So one user would have full web access while another would be restricted only to the whitelist.

I am able to block all outgoing web traffic on a per-user basis, but I cannot seem to whitelist certain websites. My current `FILTER` table is setup as:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 778 packets, 95768 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 777 packets, 95647 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       176.32.98.166        0.0.0.0/0            owner UID match 1000
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       176.32.103.205       0.0.0.0/0            owner UID match 1000
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       205.251.242.103      0.0.0.0/0            owner UID match 1000
  677 73766 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            owner UID match 1000 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

This was created with the following commands:

```sh
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -s amazon.com -m owner --uid-owner <USERNAME> -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner <USERNAME> -j REJECT
```

My understanding was that `iptables` would use the first rule that matches to a packet but it seems that is not the case here. All web traffic is being blocked for the user while being allowed for all other users. Is there another way to set this up?

Comment: I don't think any of those is your IP address? they seem to be IP addresses for Amazon's AWS console.

Comment: @MichaelHampton that's correct. I'm trying to whitelist amazon.com.

Comment: Okay I just realized I was using the `-s` flag for an outgoing packet. I should be using `-d` for the OUTPUT chain. Doing so doesn't seem to open access to the IP though. I think because the DNS is blocked.

Answer (score 1):

[Tero Kilkanen](https://serverfault.com/questions/1044283/how-can-i-use-iptables-as-a-per-user-whitelist-web-filter-on-linux?newreg=ff1653d237eb4fb28ba7f130afa70929#comment1359667_1044296) is correct. This is a fragile way to whitelist because most if not all major websites are using CDNs. Watch what happens when I try to resolve and insert a REJECT rule:

```
$ host www.amazon.com
www.amazon.com is an alias for tp.47cf2c8c9-frontier.amazon.com.
tp.47cf2c8c9-frontier.amazon.com is an alias for d3ag4hukkh62yn.cloudfront.net.
d3ag4hukkh62yn.cloudfront.net has address 13.227.254.68

$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d www.amazon.com -j REJECT

$ sudo iptables -L OUTPUT -n
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            13.227.254.68        reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

About 2 minutes later, I resolved the domain again and I already get a different IP address:

```
$ host www.amazon.com
www.amazon.com is an alias for tp.47cf2c8c9-frontier.amazon.com.
tp.47cf2c8c9-frontier.amazon.com is an alias for www.amazon.com.edgekey.net.
www.amazon.com.edgekey.net is an alias for e15316.e22.akamaiedge.net.
e15316.e22.akamaiedge.net has address 23.213.141.104
```

The best solution I've used for this situation is to use the `--ipset` feature in the `dnsmasq` DNS resolver. First create the ipset, here we name it `amazon`:

```
$ sudo ipset create amazon hash:ip

$ sudo ipset -L amazon
Name: amazon
Type: hash:ip
Revision: 2
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536
Size in memory: 128
References: 0
Members:
```

In your `dnsmasq.conf` define the domain(s) which, when resolved to IP addresses, will be added to the ipset:

```
ipset=/amazon.com/amazon
```

`amazon.com` defined above applies to all subdomains also, i.e. `*.amazon.com`. After restarting the `dnsmasq` service, use the `set` module in iptables (see `man iptables-extensions`) in your rule:

```
$ sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m set --match-set amazon dst -j REJECT
```

Now try to resolve `www.amazon.com` again and see its IP address added to the ipset:

```
$ host www.amazon.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
www.amazon.com is an alias for tp.47cf2c8c9-frontier.amazon.com.                                                                                                                                                                               
tp.47cf2c8c9-frontier.amazon.com is an alias for www.amazon.com.edgekey.net.                                                                                                                                                                   
www.amazon.com.edgekey.net is an alias for e15316.e22.akamaiedge.net.                                                                                                                                                                          
e15316.e22.akamaiedge.net has address 23.208.241.77                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
$ sudo ipset -L amazon                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Name: amazon                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Type: hash:ip                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Revision: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536                                                                                                                                                                                                
Size in memory: 176                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
References: 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Members:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
23.208.241.77
```

Once again, but using `amazon.com`:

```
$ host amazon.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
amazon.com has address 205.251.242.103                                                                                                                                                                                                         
amazon.com has address 176.32.103.205                                                                                                                                                                                                          
amazon.com has address 54.239.28.85                                                                                                                                                                                                            
amazon.com mail is handled by 5 amazon-smtp.amazon.com.                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
$ sudo ipset -L amazon                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Name: amazon                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Type: hash:ip                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Revision: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536                                                                                                                                                                                                
Size in memory: 320                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
References: 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Members:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
205.251.242.103                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
176.32.103.205                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
23.208.241.77                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
54.239.28.85
```

Confirming that the iptables rule is working by running several `curl` requests:

```
$ curl https://www.amazon.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.amazon.com port 443: Connection refused                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
$ curl https://amazon.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
curl: (7) Failed to connect to amazon.com port 443: Connection refused                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
$ curl https://aws.amazon.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
curl: (7) Failed to connect to aws.amazon.com port 443: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out thanks to @MichaelHampton 's question. Whitelisted websites should be added like so:

`sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d amazon.com -m owner --uid-owner <USERNAME> -j ACCEPT`

You will also have to open UDP port 53 to allow DNS hosts to resolve:

`sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m owner --uid-owner <USERNAME> -j ACCEPT`

And the final rule should be:

`sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner <USERNAME> -j REJECT`

Comment: Using `amazon.com` as the destination host doesn't work that well. The domain name is resolved when the rule is inserted into IPTables, and whenever `amazon.com` changes its IP addresses, the rule won't match anymore.